# Проблема с запросом на SQL

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы:

[image: схема]

Нужно вывести таблицу с такими полями: ФИО, № счета, Количество операций, Общая сумма.

Где:

- `Количество операций` это - `COUNT(Совершает.[Название операции])AS [Количество операций]`.
- `[Общая сумма]` это - `Счет.[Начальный баланс] AS [Общая сумма]`, но это поле вычисляется по следующему принципу:

  - Если `Совершает.[Название операции]='Снятие денежных средств'`, то мы отнимаем `[Размер операции]` от `[Общей суммы]`.
  - Иначе Если `Совершает.[Название операции]='Вклады денежных средств'`, то мы прибавляем `[Размер операции]` к `[Общей сумме]`.

И в конце выводим нашу таблицу тех людей, у которых общая сумма окажется одинаковой.

Comment: имхо, сам ты и не пробовал его решить, оно достаточно простое с небольшим знанием синтаксиса sql. Не видно, твоих попыток, а ты просишь сразу ответ

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
select
  max( s.ФИО ) as ФИО,
  s.НомерСчета,
  count(*) as КоличествоОпераций,
  sum(
    case o.НазваниеОперации
      when 'Снятие'
      then -1
      else 1
   end * o.РазмерОперации
  ) as СуммаОпераций
from
  Счет s,
  Совершает o
where
  s.КодСчета = o.НомерСчета
group by
  s.НомерСчета
```

Comment: На таком уровне в котором ты написал нам sql не объясняли, а  с использованием более примитивных операторов резутальтов никаких. И даже сейчас посмотрев код многие моменты не совсем понятны поэтому скоректировав твой запрос все равно не могу понять его ошибок. Ну все равно спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
select FIO as ФИО, 
       Number as Номер_сч,
       sum(Cnt) As Количество_опер,
       sum(Sum_oper)as Общая  сумма 
from (
   (select(select [ФИО]  from Счет where [#Код счета]=Совершает.[#Код совершает]) as FIO,
   (select(select [№счета]  from Счет where [#Код счета]=Совершает.[#Код совершает])as    
                                                                                  Number,
    1 as Cnt, 
 - ([Размер операции]) as Sum_oper 
        from  Совершает
      where   Совершает.[Название операции] = 'Снятие денежных средств' 
   union all
    select (select ФИО  from Счет where [#Код счета] = Совершает.[#Код совершает])  FIO,
   (select(select [№счета]  from Счет where [#Код счета]=Совершает.[#Код совершает])as    
                                                                                  Number,
    1 as Cnt,  
    [Размер операции] as Sum_oper 
     from  Совершает
    where   Совершает.[Название операции] = 'Вклады денежных средств'
 union all
     select  [ФИО] as  FIO,
            [№счета] as Number, 
              0 as Cnt,  
            [Начальный баланс] as Sum_oper 
     from  Счет
       )
  group by  FIO, Number
```